# Choosing a consistent approach to Ajax responses in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

95% of the time, I return partial views to ajax requests, dropping the response into a predefined location in the existing HTML.

But now I am wanting to develop a consistent approach to ajax responses, and the partial view system doesn't cut the mustard all the time (e.g. if I want to display additional data or error messages in the response).

I am swaying between the following 3 approaches, with pros / cons for each.

Which one(s) I go for will have a significant impact on my base models, approach to building JS plugins, etc. As I'll be deploying the approach sitewide, the data footprint of ajax responses is not insignificant.

I would like to get feedback from more seasoned developers:

- Confirming / refuting / adding to the pros / cons as I see them
- Any pitfalls or gotchas to avoid?
- Am I making mistakes - e.g. are there ways to avoid the 'cons'?
- Do you use any of these approaches in your MVC apps? Which have you found to be the best, and why?

---

**1. Return HTML PartialView**

*Pros*

- Quick and easy to implement
- Nice fit, taking advantage of MVC's built in modularity and razor templating
- Response handling in JS can be consistent and standardised - we're always dealing with a HTML result

*Cons*

- No way to provide additional data, or error feedback
- Inflexible in general
- Not massively efficient

---

**2. Return HTML as Part of a JSON Response**

*Pros*

- Most comprehensive and flexible option
- Can use razor to template the views, whilst allowing for additional data
- Response handling in JS can be partially standardised, if we use `response.Errors`, `response.SuccessHtml`, etc.

*Cons*

- The most complicated to implement - requires rendering razor views outside of a controller
- Presumably it's the most 'expensive' option - there is the overhead of templating views for the HTML and physically the most data in the response

---

**3. Return Pure JSON Response - No HTML**

*Pros*

- Quickest response in terms of data size
- I have seen this approach recommended (can't remember where)

*Cons*

- Not very MVC-ish - yes, we can use mustache or similar to template, but it would be nicer to reuse the same razor views as we do in normal page loads
- Mustache templating can get complicated if we want to start using if/else statements and other logic in our views
- Few opportunities to standardise JS response handling

Comment: *"Not very MVC-ish"* ... but neither is the big trend to single page apps if you only mean .Net MVC. Whole question is off topic due to *"primarily opinion based"*

Comment: Well, I would like to validate the pros / cons of approaches as I see them. I may not have thought of everything, and I might have some basic assumptions wrong.  I see this question as experienced based, not just opinion based.

Comment: *"Few opportunities to standardise JS response handling"* ... sure there is ... use response status codes and promises with ajax that reject when codes aren't 200

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, that is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for